# Bubble sort and selection sort

Tags: sorting

I would just like to know the key differences between these two sorting methods because they are very similar and have got me confused.

For example, if I had a sorted array:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

What would be some differences in the number of comparisons and movements between using selection and bubble sort on this sorted list.

Comment: starting point for you -- http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_bubble_sort_and_selection_sort

Comment: A simple search [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) would have been better !!!

Comment: @Bill As far as I know, bubble sort is more efficient unlike what your article states. The wikipedia links provided by Noob UnChained explain this more in detail.

Comment: @sbooob I do not own the wiki article :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, its a visual and audio representation of the behavior of different sorting algorithms. Very entertaining and educational to give you an idea how they behave.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8g-iYGHpEA

Since your list you provided is already perfectly sorted we are dealing with best case scenario for both algorthms, which is O(n) for bubble and O(n^2) for selection sort.